# Calculation of the standard deviation using mean and the percentages

Tags: statistics

I want to calculate the standard deviation using the mean and percentage.
For example:
I a class 20% students have less the 30 marks, 40% students got from 30 t0 60 marks and 40% are above 60 marks. The average score (mean) of the class is 66 marks. So how to find the standard deviation of the class.

I want to use just statistic formulas to calculate the standard deviation of the class.

Comment: Using what programming language/database/system? You could do this with a calculator app, but I suspect you have a specific use case in mind. Please consider adding language tags to your question, or at least enough information to specify how you want your solution to be framed.

Comment: I just need the formula to calculate to calculate